# Send encrypted email using Lotus notes

Tags: java, lotus-notes

Is there is a way to send encrypted email using Lotus notes using JAVA API?

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Set [EncryptOnSend](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc%2FH_ENCRYPTONSEND_PROPERTY_JAVA.html) on the `Document` to `true`, then send it using the `send` method.

> To encrypt a document when mailed, this method looks for the public
>   key of each recipient in the Domino Directory. If it cannot find a
>   recipient's public key, the method sends an unencrypted copy of the
>   document to that recipient. All other recipients receive an encrypted
>   copy of the document.