# Encrypt note with Lotus Notes API

Tags: c++, c, email, encryption, lotus-notes

I have written a simple mail client for Lotus Notes and I try to encrypt a message. My approach according to the C++ API help was the following:

```
LNMailMessage msg;
session.CreateMailMessage(&msg);     // Create new message
msg.Open();                          // Open message for editing

msg.SetRecipients(<myself>);         // Set recipients
msg.SetSubject("Encryption test");   // Set subject

if (msg.HasItem("Body"))             // Delete default body
    msg.DeleteItem("Body");

LNText body;                         // Create encrypted body field
body.SetValue("Encrypted text");
msg.CreateItem("Body", body, LNITEMFLAGS_ENCRYPT);

msg.Encrypt();                       // Encrypt message
msg.Send();                          // Send message
```

Now I have the problem, that the Encrypt() methods throws an exception, that the message cannot be encrypted because of an unopened database:

> Unable to perform operation due to unopened database

The same error message occurs, when I try to sign a message. Does anybody know, what I am doing wrong? Which database is meant? Any suggestions are welcome, also with the C API. Maybe this gives a hint.

Comment: Are you able to send non-encrypted and non-signed messages?

Comment: Yes, non-encrypted and non-signed mails are working. Even with attachments.

Comment: I just found a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813681/send-encrypted-email-using-lotus-notes. Maybe the Encrypt() method encrypts directly and EncryptOnSend let the Server do it? Is there an equivalent in the C/C++ API?

Comment: LNMailMessage inherits from LNDocument, so the equivalent of EncryptOnSend would be to cast msg to the LNDocument class, then use LNDocument::CreateItem to create a text item named "Encrypt" with value "1".  (EncryptOnSend in the LotusScript/Java/COM classes is just a shortcut to set this particular item.)  I believe the encryption still takes place on the client side, but it is worth trying this as a workaround.

Comment: I finally got it to work, by setting the described item value, directly before calling Encrypt(). I upvoted your post, but if you would make an answer from it, i would accept that. Thank you very much for your great help!

Comment: I have updated my answer.  It's a little mysterious why this worked even though the Encrypt() method did not, but I'm glad you have it working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

In view of information exchanged in comments...

Instead of using msg.encrypt(), you could try setting a text item called "Encrypt" to the value "1". This is an alternate mechanism for instructing the Send() method to encrypting email messages when they are sent.  The EncryptOnSend property in LotusScript/COM/Java API for Notes is actually just a shortcut for setting this item.   I believe the encryption still takes place on the client side, but it is worth trying this as a workaround.

I.e., LNMailMessage inherits from LNDocument, so the equivalent of EncryptOnSend would be to cast msg to the LNDocument class, then use LNDocument::CreateItem to create a text item named "Encrypt" with value "1".

**Original Answer**

I presume you are running your code on a machine that has a Notes client installed and configured with the ID file that you expect to use for sender and for the signature.  (It's not enough to just have the install completed, even though that gives you all the DLLs that you need.  You also need to go through the client set-up.)

I would check the Mail File Location, Mail File, Home Server, and (optional) Directory Server settings in the client's current Location Document and make sure that they are all set appropriately.

I would also check whether you can open up mail file on the client and manually send signed and encrypted messages.

If your code is running on a server, there's a 'Server Location Information' section at the bottom of the 'Basics' tab in the Server Document that you should check.

Comment: I suppose it's the domain's names.nsf database that's needed. To encrypt a message, you need the public key of the recipient (and not one of your own keys).

Comment: Yes, that's certainly a possibility.  But the questioner also states that the same error occurs when using the Sign() method, and signing uses the sender's private key from the ID file so it shouldn't depend on names.nsf.

Comment: My colleage also mentioned the names.nsf database, which could possibly contain the needed keys of the receivers. I already tried to just open it, before encrypting (since the message said so), but the same error occured. I am also able to decrypt messages without any additional databse open. But signing seems to need some extra information.

Comment: @Richard: I have a default Notes client installed on my desktop. It is fully functional, which means I am able to sign, encrypt and decrypt messages, use archives, sametime, ... My own client is reading the needed server and database information from the notes.ini file of the default client, so I think the data should be valid. Sent and received messages are also available in both clients.

Comment: @wls:- just a question: what's the use of the variables body and txt?

Comment: Sorry, I only copied the important parts of my application together and 'txt' it wrong here. I replaced it by 'body'. The variable itself is needed, because the C++ API does not define a default constructor of type LNText, which accepts a string.